# peewee: classname_set to json array

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to get the following json with Python peewee.

```json
{'id': 1, 'name': 'John', 'tweet_set': [{'id': 1, 'message': 'hello'},
                                        {'id': 2, 'message': 'world'}]}
```

But all I can figured out was this:

```json
{'id': 1, 'message': 'hello', 'user': {'id': 1, 'name': 'John'}}
{'id': 2, 'message': 'world', 'user': {'id': 1, 'name': 'John'}}
```

Here is my code.  Where / What can I change to get array of tweets?

```python
from peewee import *
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict, dict_to_model

db = SqliteDatabase('/tmp/a.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    name = CharField()

class Tweet(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    message = CharField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(User)

db.connect()
db.create_tables([User, Tweet])
db.close()


user_id = User.create(name="John")
Tweet.create(message="hello", user=user_id)
Tweet.create(message="world", user=user_id)

u = User.get(User.name == 'John')

for t in u.tweet_set:
    print(model_to_dict(t))
```

Comment: can u post how the data looks in db. Thank you

Comment: @zenwraight, what do you mean? it's all there in the code; I have two tables `User` and `Tweet`.  The table `User` has one row `name="John"`, and the table `Tweet` has two rows, `message="hello"` and `message="world"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
print(model_to_dict(u, backrefs=True))
```

See documentation, which contains examples: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#model_to_dict